# Add different/own icon for android app

Tags: java, android

I'm beginner at Android-programming/developing and I would like to change my own logo at my application.
I've found a folder, called 'mipmap'. I think, it could be this location where I can change it. Also I tried it without success.

Could somebody help me in this project?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @TimarBence, if the above linked question addresses your question, please delete your question. Otherwise, please edit your question to show that it is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your image in the folder "mipmap"

Go to "manifests"

Here find the line :

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Change ic_launcher to your image name

```
android:icon="@mipmap/Your_icon_name"
```